# Getting Quantiles from Classmark-based Frequency Data

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I have been struggling while writing code to get 10, 50 and 90  quantiles (a Quantile is where a sample is divided into equal-sized).  Each row is a different sample. The data in this data frame is frequency  for each class mark (represented in the columns).

```
import pandas as pd

main_folder = r'c:user/sherwood/documents/data.csv'
datos = pd.read_csv(main_folder)
datos.head()

output[1]:
    'sample_number' 'classmark1' 'classmark2' 'classmark3' ... 
                        0.37         0.44         0.52
           1          freq1_1      freq1_2       freq1_3
           2          freq2_1      freq2_2       freq2_3
           3          freq3_1      freq3_2       freq3_3
           .
           .
           .
```

The classmarks are 0.37, 0.44, 0.52 and so on. Note that the class width is not known nor equal along the distribution.
[Here is the data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEUET.png) (The right-sided column is the sample, but not used in the data frame)

> I want to figure out how to obtain the quantiles 10, 50 and 90 **for each row** by just having class marks as headers.

(In statistics a class mark is a value within a class interval, esp its midpoint or the nearest integral value, used to represent the interval for computational convenience).

Answer (score 1):

Try using .describe()

```
import pandas as pd
main_folder = r'c:user/sherwood/documents/data.csv'
datos = pd.read_csv(main_folder)
datos.describe(percentiles = [0.1,0.5,0.9]).filter( regex = '%',axis = 0)
```